# Unity, specific rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-development

I have this object that I want to rotate but I want to Clamp the possible rotation to lets say 10 degrees. For example, the rotation around Z happens while the player has the A key pressed down, comes down to 10 as it can-t go any further, and it slowly rotates back to 0 when the key is released... the same happens when u press D but in - (minus) direction ofcourse... The rotations are around a Global axes and only around Z ( with A and D keys) and around X (W and S keys)...
Hope I was clear :)

so far my code looks like this:

```
public float rotationSpeed = 100f;
    public float returnSpeed = 10f;
    private float targetAngle = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            targetAngle = Mathf.Clamp(targetAngle + rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            targetAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(targetAngle, 0, returnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, targetAngle);

    }
}
```

it works ok but when I add the condition for D it acts badly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without overthinking it too much I would say you are on the right track, yo should just not clamp between `0` and `10` but rather between `-10` and `10`

```
public float rotationSpeed = 100f;
public float returnSpeed = 10f;
private float targetAngleZ = 0f;
private float targetAngleX = 0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        targetAngleZ += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        targetAngleZ -= rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  
    }
    else
    {
        targetAngleZ = Mathf.LerpAngle(targetAngleZ, 0, returnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        targetAngleX += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        targetAngleX -= rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  
    }
    else
    {
        targetAngleX = Mathf.MoveTowards(targetAngleX, 0, returnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    targetAngleZ = Mathf.Clamp(targetAngleZ, -10, 10);
    targetAngleX = Mathf.Clamp(targetAngleX, -10, 10);
    
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetAngleX, 0, targetAngleZ);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I knew I was close! I guess I got stuck! This solves my problem. Thank you very much!